# Is it possible to use .val with a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fairly new to programming and am stuck on something that I thought would be easy! I am creating a car with the make, model, and year. I am finding the value of what the user types into the input text box and printing it on the head of the page. I am able to find the value with an ID but when I try to make it a class, it does not allow me to print it out. Can anyone shed some light on this? Thank you!!

Here is my HTML and my JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="carJquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="carjquerystylesheet.css">
    <title>Olivia's Car Challenge</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ultra' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--where your car make model and year will go-->
    <h3 id="carName">Your Car </h3></br>
    <h4 id="responseToUsersChangeInSpeed"></h4></br>
    <h4 id="currentSpeed"></h4>
    <!--we want a place for text entry for people to enter in their car info-->
    <label for="make" class="make">Enter Make</label>
    <input type="text" class="make" value="" name="make"/></br>
    <label for="model" class="model" >Enter Model</label>
    <input type="text" class="model" value="" name="model"/></br>
    <label for="year" class="year" >Enter Year</label>
    <input type="text" class="year" value="" name="year"/></br>
    <input id="createCarButton" type="button" value="Create My Car"/>

    <!--a button for increase speed-->
    <input id="accelerateButton" type="button" value="Accelerate"/>

    <!--a button for decrease speed-->
    <input id="brakeButton" type="button" value="Brake"/>

    <!--a button for the fluid increase to 70 and decrease back to 0-->
    <input id="fluidIncreaseDecreaseButton" type="button" value="Surprise!"/>

  </body>
</html>
```

JS FILE:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //allows us to change the speed of the car
      var speed = 0;
      var maxSpeed = 85;
      var brakeRate = Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 5); //sets to a random rate between 5 and 10
      var accelerateRate = Math.floor((Math.random()*21) + 10); //sets to a random rate between 10 and 30

    //A function to create the car based on the user's input
    $("#createCarButton").click (function() {
      //Create a variable to hold a string of the user's input
      var nameOfCar = $(".make").val() + ", " + $(".model").val() + ", " + $(".year").val();
      //Change the carName header to reflect the user's nameOfCar
      $("#carName").html(nameOfCar);
      //updating the user with their speed
      $("#currentSpeed").html("Your current speed is: " + speed);
      //Hide the user input boxes after the car has been created
      $(".make").hide();
      $(".model").hide();
      $(".year").hide();
      $("#createCarButton").hide();
    });

    //function which runs when the user clicks on the "Accelerate" button
    $("#accelerateButton").click(function accelerate(){
      //If they've already hit their max speed, and they still try to accelerate...
      if (speed === maxSpeed){
        //...inform them that they can't
        $("#responseToUsersChangeInSpeed").html("You can't go any faster!!");
      }
      //Otherwise, if the rate of their acceleration is less than or equal to the difference between the maxSpeed, and their speed, allow them to accelerate
      else if (accelerateRate <= (maxSpeed - speed)){
        //increase their speed by the accelerateRate
        speed += accelerateRate;
        //tell them how fast they're going
        $("#currentSpeed").html("Your current speed is: " + speed);
      }
      //Otherwise, the accelerateRate would take them over the maxSpeed, so we only let them go as fast as the maxSpeed
      else {
        //change their speed to the maxSpeed
        speed = maxSpeed;
        //tell them they've hit the max speed
        $("#responseToUsersChangeInSpeed").html("You've hit your max speed of " + maxSpeed + ". Don't even try to go faster.");
        //tell them how fast they're going
        $("#currentSpeed").html("Your current speed is: " + speed);
      }
    });

    $("#brakeButton").click(function(){
      if (speed === 0) {
        $("#responseToUsersChangeInSpeed").html("You are already at a dead stop.");
      }
      else if(brakeRate <= speed) {
        speed -= brakeRate;
        //tell them how fast they're going
        $("#currentSpeed").html("Your current speed is: " + speed);
      }
      else {
        speed = 0;
        $("#responseToUsersChangeInSpeed").html("You've come to a complete stop.");
        $("#currentSpeed").html("Your current speed is: " + speed);
      }
    });

    $("#fluidIncreaseDecreaseButton").click(function(){
      maxSpeed = 70;
      while(speed < maxSpeed) {
        $("#accelerateButton").click();
        $("#currentSpeed").html("Your current speed is: " + speed);
        console.log(speed);
      };
      while(speed > 0) {
        $("#brakeButton").click();
        $("#currentSpeed").html("Your current speed is: " + speed);
        console.log(speed);
      };
      $("#brakeButton").click();
    });
});
```

Comment: So, you are saying that this doesn't work:  `$(".make").val()`?

Comment: You have two elements with a class of make, only one of those two has a .val() method (the input, not the label).  Use this instead to grab the value:
$('input.make').val(); Same goes for the model and year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your HTML code contains more than one element with needed class, using `$(".make")` selects all elements having class "make". It also selects them with ordering related to the appearing order in the HTML. So when your first "make" element in HTML is "label" and the second is "input", they will have the same ordering inside jQuery selection result: `[<label>, <input>]`

When you call `.val()` for jQuery selection result, it returns value of first element in the result. And, because the first element is "label", which is not a form input (either "input", "button", "textarea", or "select"), the `$(".make").val()` returns empty string.

For selecting and using value of exactly "input" element, you need to use `$("input.make").val()`, `$("input.model").val()`, and `$("input.year").val()` instructions.

Also, it's possible to select form elements with their names: `$('input[name="make"]')` or even `$('[name="make"]')`. It will be something like this:

```
var nameOfCar = $('[name="make"]').val() + ", " + $('[name="model"]').val() + ", " + $('[name="year"]').val();
```

But, I think, more readable variation is:

```
var nameOfCar = $("input.make").val() + ", " + $("input.model").val() + ", " + $("input.year").val();
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your detailed explanation, it makes sense now. I just tried it out and it works!

Comment: @Olivia I'm happy if I helped. Also, please consider to read this help article about answers on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are assigning same class name to input and label. So, jquery does not know which one to use

Answer (score 0):

`$(".make").val()` will not return anything because you have 2 elements with `class="make"` a label and input, and since the label came first in the DOM `$(".make").val()` will try to get the value of the label.

Try change that code to `$("input.make").val()` this will get the value of the input with class="make"

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp has good explanation of how the jQuery selectors work.

Answer (score -1):

Both your label and input has the class ".make". So when you try to use $('.make') jQuery will return an array (as it selects both elements with the class ".make").

Try $('input.make').val().